# Destroy component by itself - angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have component (`main-cmp`) with rows from database. 
For rows I create another component for eg. `row-cmp`

`main-cmp` have requested data from database, and parse it as

```
<row-cmp *ngFor="let row of data" 
     [id]="row.id" 
     [name]="row.name" 
     [value]="row.value">
</row-cmp>
```

In `row-cmp` I have declare `delete()` function who call http request to my backend. Now when response from request is true I want to destroy `row-cmp` for selected row. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not supported. I'd suggest to add an eventemitter

```
@Output() delete:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

and then add an event handler that removes the item from the data array

```
<row-cmp *ngFor="let row of data;let i=index" (delete)="data.splice(i,1)"
     [id]="row.id" 
     [name]="row.name" 
     [value]="row.value">
</row-cmp>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working for me :) Have a nice day! :DDD